# How to use JSON_EXTRACT to get values of a string index

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have the followed data rows:
[image]

I'm trying to use JSON_EXTRACT to get rows only if inside jot_locale_vars has index equals "2".

```
SELECT 
    jot.*, 
    (JSON_EXTRACT(`jot_locale_vars`, '$[2]')) as localeVar 
    
FROM job_type jot 
WHERE jot_excluded = ''
HAVING localeVar IS NOT NULL
```

But, as you can see, i've been used `$[2]`, but the array indexes start to zero. So... String 1 equals to `[0]`, 2 equals `[1]`... and i cant use in this way.

How can i extract values if has condition by a string index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to see if a *key* exists inside of an object, then you'll want to use [`JSON_CONTAINS_PATH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains-path).

```
SELECT `jot`.*,
    `jot_locale_vars`->'$[*]."2"' AS `localeVar`
FROM `job_type` AS `jot` 
WHERE `jot_excluded` = 0
AND JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(`jot_locale_vars`, 'one', '$[*]."2"')
```

<sub>Note: This requires MySQL 5.7+</sub>
<sub>Note 2: The [`->`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path) operator is just shorthand for `JSON_EXTRACT()`.</sub>

---

The syntax for the path can be found at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-path-syntax

I'm using `$[*]."2"`, which means "any array value" (`[*]`) that contains a key named `"2"` (`."2"`).

Comment: Nice! Almost there! Now, can i get the key values on a alias field, like my example?

Comment: @MaykelEsser Check the updated answer, you can just use `JSON_EXTRACT()` with the same path.